# Is there any situation the TF-IDF is worse that using term-frequency vectors?

Tags: nlp, mahout, tf-idf, term-document-matrix

I am doing text classification now. Is there any situation the TF-IDF is worse that using term-frequency vectors? How to explain it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Both metrics ...discriminate along two dimensions – informativeness (IDF) and aboutness (TF)
>
> Documents that contain hundreds of occurrences of some high IDF term are going
> to result in poor, noisy matches ... in ex. spam documents

A good read - [Beyond bags of words](http://maroo.cs.umass.edu/pub/web/getpdf.php?id=779), (Donald A. Metzler Jr. 2007)

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand discriminate informativeness (IDF) and aboutness (TF) How to explain it? Thanks

Comment: if a frequency of a term is very high in a document, one can state that the document is about that term to a certain degree (TF) 
Common terms that are met in a lot of documents are considered noise (in ex: the, this, ...) they will no bring new information to the document or very little (IDF). Take some time to read the linked article it will you a better view on the matter. In most of the cases the combination of TF-IDF is better than TF alone. These are both term weighting schemes that can be applied on term vectors. Cheers

Comment: @IonCojocaru I have the opposite question...is there any case when IDF is better than TF-IDF? As far I understood TF is important to give a weight to a word within a document to match that document with a predefined query. If I'd like just to sort the importance of words in a collection of documents without any specific IR purpose, why should I use the TF term?